# Blazor 404 page not showing if router is mismatched

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am working on Blazor POC and got stuck on routing. I have implemented some routing on the page but if some route is not configured and trying to load from browser than getting only "Loading..." text on browsers

Below the App.razor file

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
</Found>
<NotFound>
    @*<LayoutView Layout="@typeof(BlazorWorkshop.Web.Client.Pages.Error404)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>*@

    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
</NotFound>
```

Index.html is given below

```
<body id="page-top">
<app>
    Loading...
</app>

<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
```

Getting error in console:

net::ERR_ABORTED 404

A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
[image]
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost:44336/product/') with script ('https://localhost:44336/product/service-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Error is updated in question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this question while having a similar (if not the same) problem. If you look at the error, you'll notice it's not loading your resources off the root URL. For me, adding the following to the head of my index.html worked:

```
<base href="/" />
```